# Looking for WAMP/LAMP/MAMP Benchmarking

Tags: performance, wampserver

I'm running ZWAMP WAMP stack on my local development machine. However I have found it to be very slow at serving pages from a Drupal site I have setup. By contrast, my live production site on shared hosting is reasonably quick.

For me the goal with a local WAMP stack was to develop offline and send completed work to the live production site.

I liked ZWAMP because it didn't require adjustments to User Access Control or other permissions.

I've looked at Drupal Acquia Development Stack but found this too restrictive: only one site instance/doc root can be installed.

I've looked at other DAMP stacks and heard reports of them being slow.

My local development machine that I am running the WAMP stack on is a Dual Core 2.6Ghz hyperthreaded Intel i7, 4Gb RAM, 7200rpm hard disk, running Windows 64bit professional. Surely this is fast enough.

So I'm looking for:

- Causes of the slowness of the WAMP and how to improve the speed
- Benchmark data of various WAMP stacks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're after. Part of why  performance is so different on your home computer is that your host isn't generally running things like fancy(if you've left various effects on) windowing systems like Windows' Aero. If you're trying to compare speed, you shouldn't spend much time benchmarking Windows running WAMP, but instead setting up an environment that's actually comparable(ish) to the production server. Raw hardware stats like your CPU don't mean much if they're not actually doing the same things. (For what it's worth, I'll agree Drupal speed tends to suck locally.)

Comment: From my experience, I've found MySQL on Windows (home PC style) to be VERY slow. PHPMyAdmin provides some nice statistics for that, and I have a hunch that's whats making it slow.

Comment: +1 Su': what you say makes sense: one should be attempting to replicate a host environment not only for compatibility reasons to run the code but also to benefit from the convenience of developing locally (speed and staging in-progress work).

Comment: +1 ionFish: - for the PHPMyAdmin stats - what do you think the bottleneck is likely to be?

Answer (score 1):

I am seriously considering a VirtualBox environment on my Windows machine to run a flavour of Linux and a LAMP stack with my Drupal site(s) on. Hopefully this doesn't have the same bottle necks as the WAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

You will experience a difference in performance anyway, regardless of what environment you use.

I used to use WampServer and I would find this quite slow sometimes, similar to what you have explained. I then started using XAMPP and have found it to run much better, although sites on my XAMPP installation are still noticeably slower.

Recently though I have developed on my laptop which runs Fedora 17, using Apache, MySQL and BlueFish as an editor. This has been the best solution for me in terms of performance. You could use a VirtualBox instance, but I feel that this may just slow your computer down altogether. I would try XAMPP first, and if your problems still persist try maybe dual-booting to a Linux instance.

Comment: My development machine is a Mac Book Pro with dual boot. MAMP on Mac OS X (mamp.info) performs reasonably well - much much faster than XAMPP on Windows natively (via BootCamp). MAMP therefore is good enough for me at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand, you said your development PC ran Windows?

Comment: Yes, it does: It's an Intel MacBookPro and I use MacOS AND Windows on it, via BootCamp. I have been evaluating which *AMP stacks to use - perhaps I should rewrite the question to include MAMP, LAMP and WAMP.